# How to fix NaN record being dropped when using pivot_table method?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I have a dataframe df as :

```
var1 var2 var3       var4
a    1    1/1/2020   3
a    2    2/1/2020   2
a    3    3/1/2020   NaN
```

When I try to pivot it as

```
pivot = (df.pivot_table(index=['var2','var3'], columns=['var1'], values='var4')
                                              .reset_index()
                                              .rename_axis(None, axis=1))
```

It drops the record with NaN in the var4 to give result as:

```
var2  var3         a
1     1/1/2020     3
2     2/1/2020     2
```

What I am trying to get is:

```
var2  var3         a
1     1/1/2020     3
2     2/1/2020     2
3     3/1/2020     NaN
```

Any ideas why its dropping the NaN record during pivot and how to fix that behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `set_index().unstack()`:

```
df.set_index(['var2','var3','var1'])['var4'].unstack()
```

Output:

```
var1             a
var2 var3         
1    1/1/2020  3.0
2    2/1/2020  2.0
3    3/1/2020  NaN
```

Comment: tried, but it drops var2 and var3 from the new output so i can't see whether the NaNs were retained or not when i throw the output in the csv file. ANy idea how i can retain the var2 and var 3 in the output?

Comment: Chain with `reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)` as in your `pivot_table` method.

Comment: right of course. YEah works beautifully! Thanks a ton